# How to set trigger 'click' on the next hidden row in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can I set to trigger 'click' on the next hidden row in jQuery?

```
  $('.js-data-selector .aspect-data:first').trigger('click');
```

Above is the code for triggering on the first row.

Comment: ` $('.js-data-selector .aspect-data:first').next().trigger('click');` assuming the selector is the row before the hidden tro

Comment: Can you include an example of the markup? Where is the next hidden row compared to the first row? Is it the 2nd row? Are they farther apart?

Comment: Some rows are hidden according to another filter used. Hidden row is always the immediate next of the currently selected row.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

`$('.js-data-selector .aspect-data:first').next().trigger('click');`

assuming the selector is the row before the hidden tr

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

`$('.js-data-selector .aspect-data:first').siblings('.classnameiftr').trigger('click');`

assuming the selector is not the row before the hidden tr

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.